# How to replace every six row in a data set with its lag starting from 7th row

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, xts

I want to replace every sixth row in `xts` from a data set with its lag. This process should start from the 7th row, which means that the 7th row will be replaced by the 6th row, the 13th row will be replaced by 12th row, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an easy way using subsetting:

```
myxts <- xts::xts(x = 1:100, order.by = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2019-10-17"), by = "d", length.out = 100))

myxts[1:floor(nrow(myxts) / 6) * 6 + 1, ] <- myxts[1:floor(nrow(myxts) / 6) * 6, ] 

2019-10-17    1
2019-10-18    2
2019-10-19    3
2019-10-20    4
2019-10-21    5
2019-10-22    6
2019-10-23    6
2019-10-24    8
2019-10-25    9
2019-10-26   10
2019-10-27   11
2019-10-28   12
2019-10-29   12
2019-10-30   14
2019-10-31   15
```

Comment: running this code is giving this error Error in `[.xts`(x, i, which.i = TRUE) : subscript out of bounds

Comment: can you replicate this example with 192 columns

Comment: strange. I just tried with a fresh R session and it works perfectly.
Can you restart R and try again?
If it does not work: which R version are you using?
And can you post the output of `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: This should also work for multiple columns in the same way it works for one.

Comment: ok R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)

Comment: which version of `xts` are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201027/discussion-between-cettt-and-jeetkamal).

Answer (score 1):

The code below will subtract 1 from the index if the index is 1 after a multiple of 6. So 7 will become index 6, 13 will become 12, etc. Subsetting your xts object with this new index will give the result you describe

```
i <- seq(nrow(myxts))
myxts[i - (i %% 6L == 1L),]
```

Comment: Thanks Sir you save my day